# How should I save the previous data in check box in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-developer-api

**Background** - Here's the scenario, my app is an IOT app. Now the case is I have to create a group of IOT devices in Room Section. But the condition is always same type of devices must be selected in that Group like if in room there are 4 devices, where 2 support RGB and other support Warm and Cool White then the Group when I will create It will show all devices with checkboxes with different categorie. And If i tick on any device then other devices categories will be get disabled (not the same one). Cause I want to make the user to create the group of same category.

**Problem** - Now as I mention the problem it couldn't save it if i didn't make any change in group.

```
private fun createSelectedDevices() {
        val selectedNodes = JsonArray()
        val disSelectedNodes = JsonArray()
        val distinctDevices = devices.distinctBy { it.nodeId } as ArrayList<Device>

        if (selectedDevices.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            //Error happening when we edit the Group Name or not
            alertErrorManagement(
                "Please select devices",
                "",
                ErrorObject.EXCEPTION,
                R.drawable.ic_error_background
            )
            return
        } else {
            for (device in selectedDevices) {
                if (device.selectedState == 1) {
                    selectedNodes.add(device.nodeId)
                } else {
                    disSelectedNodes.add(device.nodeId)
                }
            }

            if (selectedNodes.isEmpty && disSelectedNodes.isEmpty) {
                alertErrorManagement(
                    "Please select devices",
                    "",
                    ErrorObject.EXCEPTION,
                    R.drawable.ic_error_background
                )
                return
            }
        }

        if (!disSelectedNodes.isEmpty) {
            updateGroupRemove(disSelectedNodes, selectedNodes)
        } else {
            updateGroupAdd(selectedNodes)
        }

    }
```

Now in this code alertErrorManagement is a pop up message that will show when user didn't select any devices (And while editing the group I have give user the permission to change it's group name too). Now suppose you have created a group of 1 device. If you try to click on edit button in  group and not change anything  like group name or devices selection and directly click on Save button. It will show pop up message of **Please Select Devices** which is wrong cause there is already 1 node or device is already selected. And in the code its mention above if-condition. But if I select the same device and untick the checkbox. And after that if i click on same device and tick the checkbox. It will show pop up message of **Group Updated Successfully**.

I tried to see the SelectedDevice.kt class file but I didn't see any error in there.

```
public class SelectiveDevice implements Serializable {

    private String nodeId;
    private String deviceName;
    private String userVisibleName;
    private String deviceType;
    private String primaryParamName;
    private ArrayList<Param> params;
    private boolean expanded;
    private int selectedState;

    public boolean isBluetooth = false;

    public boolean selected = false;

    private String type = "";

    public SelectiveDevice() {
    }

    public SelectiveDevice(SelectiveDevice device) {

        nodeId = device.getNodeId();
        deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
        userVisibleName = device.getUserVisibleName();
        deviceType = device.getDeviceType();
        primaryParamName = device.getPrimaryParamName();
        params = device.getParams();
        expanded = device.isExpanded();
        selectedState = device.getSelectedState();
    }

    public SelectiveDevice(SelectiveDevice device, boolean selected, String type) {

        nodeId = device.getNodeId();
        deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
        userVisibleName = device.getUserVisibleName();
        deviceType = device.getDeviceType();
        primaryParamName = device.getPrimaryParamName();
        params = device.getParams();
        expanded = device.isExpanded();
        selectedState = device.getSelectedState();
        this.selected = selected;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public SelectiveDevice(Device device, boolean selected, String type) {

        nodeId = device.getNodeId();
        deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
        userVisibleName = device.getUserVisibleName();
        deviceType = device.getDeviceType();
        primaryParamName = device.getPrimaryParamName();
        params = device.getParams();
        expanded = device.isExpanded();
        selectedState = device.getSelectedState();
        this.selected = selected;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public SelectiveDevice(String id) {
        nodeId = id;
    }

    public String getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getUserVisibleName() {
        return userVisibleName;
    }

    public void setUserVisibleName(String userVisibleName) {
        this.userVisibleName = userVisibleName;
    }

    public String getDeviceType() {
        return deviceType;
    }

    public void setDeviceType(String deviceType) {
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
    }

    public String getPrimaryParamName() {
        return primaryParamName;
    }

    public void setPrimaryParamName(String primaryParamName) {
        this.primaryParamName = primaryParamName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Param> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(ArrayList<Param> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public int getSelectedState() {
        return selectedState;
    }

    public void setSelectedState(int selectedState) {
        this.selectedState = selectedState;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EspDevice {" +
                "node id = '" + nodeId + '\'' +
                "name = '" + deviceName + '\'' +
                ", type ='" + deviceType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

}
```

As a Fresher in Android, I didn't get much idea of where I should see else.

Comment: Did you try using DataStore ? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore